# How to make Semi-transparent color over image?

Tags: html, css, transparent, card

I want to create a semi-transparent color layer where I want to type title and description of image but due to some reason I am not able to make the changes or fulfill my goal. Can anyone help me to solve the issue? I am not able to overlay the transparent layer over image as it is on same card.

I want to create like below image:

[image]

My HTML code is here:

```css
.container{
  max-width: none;
}
.container-fluid, .container-sm, .container-md, .container-lg, .container-xl {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.card {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0 !important;
}
section {
  overflow: hidden;
}   
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}   
[data-aos^=fade][data-aos^=fade].aos-animate {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.card .entry {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
  background: #ea8537;

}   
.entry:hover{
  background: #ffcc00;  
  transition: 1.2s;
  transform: scale(1.01);

}
article, aside, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}   
.card .entry .entry-img {
  max-height: 400px;
  margin: -20px -20px 20px -20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
}
.img:hover{
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.card .entry .entry-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.card .entry .entry-title a {
  color:    #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card .entry .entry-content a {
  color:    #FFFFFF;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.card .entry .entry-meta {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #000;
}
.align-items-stretch {
  align-items: stretch !important;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="card" class="card">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch" data-aos="fade-up">
          <article class="entry">
            <div id="img1" type="image" class="entry-img">
              <img src="" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <h2 class="entry-title">
              <a href="">
                <div id="txt1" type="text"></div>
              </a>
            </h2>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>
                <div id="txt2" type="text"></div>
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you please add a working demo on https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla

Comment: @SwarajGandhi https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-microservice-sp692

Answer (score 0):

You can use very simple structure like this:

HTML:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455582916367-25f75bfc6710?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
}

h3, p {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h3>This is the title</h3>
      <p>This is the main content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah..it works fine but the problem is image and text will be edit daily so I can't give direct link and default text.

Comment: You can update the html and css dynamically via js, you can make an admin panel where they just have to enter header, description and image link, and you can generate the whole above html and create new cards each time